# Why I cannot change the owner of files in a mounted directory?

Tags: 20.04, chown, ownership

I used the following command to mount a remote directory on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tidy   //192.168.1.11/tidy-mine  /media/tidy/f_folder/
```

When I use the command `ls -l`, the owner of the files are shown as `root:root`.

I use the following command to change the owner of the files:

```
sudo chown -R digital:digital  /media/tidy/f_folder/
```

But still the owner of the files are `root:root`, as is shown by `ls -l` command.

Comment: Because the server at 192.168.1.11 suppresses `root` access. Check the server's ligs

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tidy,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000  //192.168.1.11/tidy-mine  /media/tidy/f_folder/
```

In above, I obtained the value of `uid` and gid``` by using the command `id`.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319000/5595353) was helpful.